# Any possible cause of gradually increasing memory utilization on azure mysql database?

Tags: mysql, azure

1. I have checked that my slow query file is slowly increasing from 30-40mb normal to 200+mb per day.
2. We are planning to revise queries put index.

Is there any services in azure where you can check what is the cause of increasing memory ulitzation?

Currently we are in a 5vcore setup which is equivalent to 40gb of ram, 52gb/500gb of data and

innodb_bufferpoolsize = 16gb
vcore(ram) = 40gb
storage = 52gb/500gb

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; could be used for a CURRENT PICTURE.  3 hours later another SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; could be compared to get some clues on what is using RAM.

Comment: Fragmented Tables contributes to additional delays (longer completion time).  Identify long running queries with Slow Query Log and identify tables to be OPTIMIZE'd to minimize fragmentation delays.

Comment: Indexes can occasionally become unreliable and extend completion times.  ANALYZE TABLE table_name or SHOW INDEX FROM table_name and OPTIIMIZE TABLE table_name all cause index recreation when run.  ONLY ONE of these operations needs to be completed for a single table.

Comment: I have checked the processlist of our dbserver and it only shows on normal connections with only 100-150 out of 1250 max connections.

Comment: I do not understand "Currently we are in a 5vcore setup which is equivalent to 40gb of ram, 52gb/500gb of data and

innodb_bufferpoolsize = 16gb vcore(ram) = 40gb storage = 52gb/500gb"

Comment: I mean this is for your 2nd question regarding the memory utlization.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) last 100 lines of your Slow Query Log, please.
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the slowlog, that is a "file" or a "table", not "memory".  If that file is growing faster and faster, then look at the file.  It is best to "digest" it first, then work on the first few queries in the digest.  [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

If you are talking about some other "memory utilization", then provide the size of RAM, the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and now much data is in all your tables.

Comment: I have checked the slow query logs but it is showing queries with 0-1 sec duration only.

For the memory utlization, i have updated my information above, thanks rick!